Text on one side of the page should be printed in the same location as the line on the other side of the page
I want to duplex print on very thin paper, and ensure vertical alignment of the paragraph text between the front and back of the paper.
If they are not aligned, the text of the back will show-through between the lines of the text in the front, which I want to avoid.
If there no headings on a page, there is no issue. But how can I make sure that the vertical space after a heading is such, that the text of paragraph following the heading (section/subsection) vertically aligns with the paragraph text on the previous page?

see the answers under the [tag:grid-typesetting] tag

Very helpful. But I would want to avoid switching to Context. I only have headings and paragraph text. Only the paragraphs would need to be on the grid. Any further suggestions for LaTeX?  I tried the grid package, but it seems limited to two columns.

there are 128 posts in that grid link  surely most of them don't suggest switching to context?
